# React Native: Zoom Android SDK: "startMeetingWithParams" starts a meeting as a participant - need it to start a meeting as host

Tags: android, react-native, zoom-sdk, zoomus

**"startMeetingWithParams" starts a meeting as a participant - need it to start a meeting as host:**
I'm trying to create a simple app with the [react-native-zoom-us](https://github.com/mieszko4/react-native-zoom-us) open source project which is claimed to be acting as a minimum bridge to the "zoom android sdk". The zoom android sdk is being accessed in this bridge through importing "us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK". The basic functionality provided by it includes startMeetingWithParams() function of the MeetingService of the android sdk. In the code (attached below), I can see that they are setting StartMeetingParamsWithoutLogin() with certain params and then passing it as an argument to startMeetingWithParams(). This is starting a meeting with user as a participant (even when host_id of the meeting is set in the parameter "userId") and the default waiting room screen shows up waiting for the host to start the meeting, whereas it is expected to start the meeting as the host. Please give your inferences on this and let me know what needs to be done to solve this. And does something have to be done with the StartMeetingOptions? Also what is the userType parameter here? It is said to be 'integer: 2' for a pro user. However, I'm not sure what type of a zoom user I am. Kindly let me know how I can know about the userType.

```
@ReactMethod
  public void startMeeting(
    final String displayName,
    final String meetingNo,
    final String userId,
    final int userType,
    final String zoomAccessToken,
    final String zoomToken,
    Promise promise
  ) {
    try {
      meetingPromise = promise;

      ZoomSDK zoomSDK = ZoomSDK.getInstance();
      if(!zoomSDK.isInitialized()) {
        promise.reject("ERR_ZOOM_START", "ZoomSDK has not been initialized successfully");
        return;
      }

      final MeetingService meetingService = zoomSDK.getMeetingService();
      if(meetingService.getMeetingStatus() != MeetingStatus.MEETING_STATUS_IDLE) {
        long lMeetingNo = 0;
        try {
          lMeetingNo = Long.parseLong(meetingNo);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          promise.reject("ERR_ZOOM_START", "Invalid meeting number: " + meetingNo);
          return;
        }

        if(meetingService.getCurrentRtcMeetingNumber() == lMeetingNo) {
          meetingService.returnToMeeting(reactContext.getCurrentActivity());
          promise.resolve("Already joined zoom meeting");
          return;
        }
      }

      StartMeetingOptions opts = new StartMeetingOptions();
      StartMeetingParamsWithoutLogin params = new StartMeetingParamsWithoutLogin();
      params.displayName = displayName;
      params.meetingNo = meetingNo;
      params.userId = userId;
      params.userType = userType;
      params.zoomAccessToken = zoomAccessToken;
      // params.zoomToken = zoomToken;

      int startMeetingResult = meetingService.startMeetingWithParams(reactContext.getCurrentActivity(), params, opts);
      Log.i(TAG, "startMeeting, startMeetingResult=" + startMeetingResult);

      if (startMeetingResult != MeetingError.MEETING_ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        promise.reject("ERR_ZOOM_START", "startMeeting, errorCode=" + startMeetingResult);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      promise.reject("ERR_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION", ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: hey can you tell how you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To work with api, you need to upgrade your subscription to paid user. To check that you should be able to host meetings greater than 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ZOOM Android SDK reference here https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/sdk-reference/android-reference:

and after taking look at the SDK source code, these are the values for userTypes:

```
int USER_TYPE_API_USER = 0;
int USER_TYPE_ZOOM = 1;
int USER_TYPE_FACEBOOK = 2;
int USER_TYPE_GOOGLE_OAUTH = 3;
int USER_TYPE_SSO = 4;
int USER_TYPE_UNKNOWN = -1;
```

As you can see, it references the way, how user was logged in.
I decided to use USER_TYPE_API_USER, as I needed to download Zoom Access Token (via using Zoom API).

I also created tutorial about inegrating Zoom SDK into React Native here:
https://stefanmajiros.medium.com/how-to-integrate-zoom-sdk-into-react-native-47492d4e46a6